# Hide and Show Code doesnt work on other forms

Tags: c#, forms, show-hide

In form 1

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\ALLENSQL;Initial Catalog=TITOMSLogin;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlDataAdapter sdf = new SqlDataAdapter("select usertype, fullname, position from login where username= '" + txtuser.Text + "' and password='" + txtpass.Text + "'", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sdf.Fill(dt);
            string fullname = dt.Rows[0]["FullName"].ToString();
            string position = dt.Rows[0]["Position"].ToString();
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
             {
                 this.Hide();
                 if (dt.Rows[0]["Usertype"].ToString() == "Admin")
                 {
                    Form2Admin ss = new Form2Admin(position + ": " + fullname);
                    Form3Admin sa = new Form3Admin(position + ": " + fullname);
                    Form5 sw = new Form5(position + ": " + fullname);
                    ss.Show();
                    sa.Hide();
                    sw.Hide();
                 }
```

now this code doesn't work in other forms

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form3Admin.Show();
        }
```

this is the scenarios I am trying to achieve:

1. After pressing login form2 will show up, form 3 and form 4 is hidden.
2. button in form 2 is press (Form 2 will hide, Form 3 will show).
3. button in form 3 is press (Form 3 will hide, Form 4 will show).
4. button in form 4 is press (form 4 will hide, Form 2 will show but all data written before must still be there) and so on to the other forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the same actual `Form3Admin` instance to Show it. Keep `Form3Admin sa` instance as a class variable and use that instance when you want to show it.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    sa.Show();
}
```

Comment: tried this but "sa" has an error: the name 'sa' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Have you created Form3Admin sa; property in the class level and assign it on button1_Click?

Comment: Sorry I am kinda lost at the moment. Could you provide an example. I am new to c# and get confused with terms.

Comment: Change this 'Form3Admin sa = new Form3Admin(position + ": " + fullname);' as 'sa = new Form3Admin(position + ": " + fullname);' in your button1 click. In the Form1 class level create 'Form3Admin sa;'. This way you use the same instance to show/hide. Otherwise you create multiple Form3Admin objects.

Comment: works on form 2 but still does not work in other forms. attach is the link for the image of error. https://imgur.com/pfNAdX9 ...... Form 1: https://imgur.com/VtxvcGM  ....... https://imgur.com/X9k51Ns

Comment: That's because you haven't set the sa variable. Without setting it, it is null.

Comment: this question may be dumb to you, but how do you set the sa variable.

Comment: Set it to the Form3Admin object where ever you create it. EG: sa = new Form3Admin(position + ": " + fullname);